# Child class inheriting from Multiple parents c++

Tags: c++

I am making a windows console rpg for a project, I changed a class from inheriting 1 parent class, and taking in an object, to inheriting 2 parent classes, it's causing issues when I run it now as the second base class is undefined
The header class is below

```
 #include "GameObject.h"
  #include "BattleObject.h"
  #include "Player.h"  
  #include "Weapon.h"
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Monster :
    public GameObject,
    public BattleObject
{
private :
    string m_name;
    vector<string> m_drops;

public:
    Monster(std::pair<int, int> coordinates, string name, vector<string> drops, int health, int attack, int defence);
    string getName();

};
```

I expect it to take in 2 base classes, but it won't run because of this

it Crashes and and says Battle Object base class is undefined.

Comment: _it Crashes and and says Battle Object base class is undefined_ copy&paste the message.

Comment: you put `using namespace std` in a header?  Wow, you don't want to do that

Comment: Does BattleObject have a no-args constructor? If yes, is it defined?

Comment: So does it crash (which happens during execution), or does it say that class is undefined (which is the linker error)? It can't be both. Please provide [mcve] with a clear problem description.

Comment: The error is exactly what is said: "BattleObject" is undefined, check if in BattleObject.h this class is defined or just forward declared.

Comment: Show us BattleObject.h.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

you should probably explicitly call the appropriate constructor of each baseclass as maybe they don't have an implicit constructor:

```
Monster(...) : GameObject(...), BattleObject(...) { ... }
```